# VPN kill switch on DD-WRT and OpenVPN

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt, openvpn

I followed the [DD-WRT: VPN OpenVPN Setup](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ddwrt_openvpn) to configure the VPN connection on my router. Apparently i use [privateinternetaccess](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) as a VPN provider and OpenVPN. It works fine, but there is no VPN kill switch! Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a "vpn kill switch" exactly?

Comment: To pause all up / download while i am not on the vpn

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ssh/telnet into the router and perform the following command:

```
 killall openvpn
```

If you need to restart the vpn, the command would be something like:

```
 openvpn --config <location of your client.conf>
```

Answer (score 1):

Under Administration --> Commands copy-paste the following and press "Save Firewall".

```
# --- SEAMLESS TUNNEL ---
# http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=957052
if [ "$(nvram get wan_proto)" == "pppoe" ]; then
    WAN_IF="$(nvram get pppoe_ifname)"
elif [ "$(nvram get wan_proto)" == "pptp" ]; then
    WAN_IF="$(nvram get pptp_ifname)"
else
    WAN_IF="$(nvram get wan_ifname)"
fi

iptables -I FORWARD -o $WAN_IF -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -I FORWARD -o $WAN_IF -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Ref: http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=957052